# Relatively better solution to pagination for complex (multiple table joint) query?

Tags: mysql, performance, join, backend

I'm trying to implement a query function for hotels. Below I will describe simplified situation to show the problems.

When query, caller can specify:

1. Dates of checkin and checkout.
2. Expected price range.
3. Location.
4. Page and limit for pagination.

My sql design:

```
Hotel { id: Int, location: Str }
Room { id: Int, hotel_id: Int, config_id: Int }
RoomConfig { id: Int, price: Decimal }
Availability { room_id: Int, date: Date } // Containing available rooms for coming 30 days.
```

Corresponding to the spec., I tried to:

1. Query `RoomConfig` to get caller-expected room configs.
2. Query `Room` to get rooms with these configs.
3. Group `Availability` by `date`, count entries in given date range to filter rooms.
4. Get hotels owning these rooms.
5. Filter hotels by `Location` in `Hotel`.

My current solution is to query intermediate IDs in my Java code and query multiple times, which has several problems:

1. Multiple trips around business server and database.
2. I have no ideas about how to do proper pagination in the situation. e.g., I can't predict how many available rooms I need to generate 20 satisfying hotels.

Another possible way is to just join all of them then use offset and limit in SQL. Related concerns includes:

1. It's so complex a procedure involving 4 tables that I'm afraid that SQL engine can not optimize well enough.
2. It makes future optimizations like moving `Availability` to cache layer like Redis impossible.

I'm not very familiar with database so please correct me if anything above appear ridiculous. Hope for some guide on choice between the two or something better, Thx!

Comment: general rule of thumb: query a database to get the data you need no more no less.  If deisgned appropriatly; RDBMS databases with proper indexs will provide set based data easily and effectively.  a four table join with proper indexes is nothing for a engine to handle.   So your #1 fear is unfounded in my opinion.  per #2... not sure how a database design would limit such .  In my opinion you have a parameterized query passing in the options the user wants to return a data set limiting to user selected parameters... 1 trip and done...  Iterating though locally is inefficient.

Comment: I suggest starting by looking through some of the many posts on here related to storing and querying room availability and/or bookings - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+room+availability

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, plus a tentative `SELECT` with `JOINs` (presumably) between all 4 tables.  We can critique it from there.